# SharePoint 2013 storage reporting tool

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Is there any kind of helpful tool for looking up at the data stored on the SharePoint 2013.

I'm thinking in the lines of TreeSize or a similar program.

I'm NOT thinking of out-of-the-box SharePoint 2013 functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I never seen that kind of tool, which give you the detailed about whole farm(data stored).

But you can check the site collection wise using the SharePoint storage metrics.
http://sharepointhoster.com/how-do-i-track-my-storage-usage-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Also I think also take a look of metalogix StoragePoint.

Answer (score 1):

TreeSize supports scanning SharePoint Servers since V6.3, including last access / change date and the "Age of Files" and "File Type" statistics:

http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/scan-ftp-and-sharepoint-servers.shtml

Full disclosure: I am the author of TreeSize Professional.